# Wie nützlich und verbreitet ist der Begriff Zustandspassiv?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, passive, participle

Nach gängigen Regeln gilt:

> - Die Tür wurde geöffnet. — Vorgangspassiv
> - Die Tür ist geöffnet. — Zustandspassiv

Intuitiv lese ich den zweiten Satz einfach als Kopula mit Prädikativ (syntaktisch äquivalent zu „Die Tür ist offen“). Damit habe ich mich neulich leider etwas blamiert. Beim Versuch, meine Bildungslücke zu schließen, bin ich aber auf große Schwierigkeiten gestoßen:

- Alle Definitionen des Zustandspassivs sind schwammig bis konfus und strotzen nur vor *aber/meistens/außer/manchmal/Ausnahme*.
- Keine Beschreibung enthält auch nur den Hauch einer Rechtfertigung für die Einführung eines dritten Genus Verbi.
- Ich erkenne keinen Bezug zur Syntax. Der Zustandspassiv wird rein semantisch definiert und eignet sich damit bestenfalls als Stilmittel.

Ich finde das gruselig, und nur die Netiquette hält mich davon ab, meine Meinung näher auszuführen. Ich möchte hier aber keine Diskussion über den Sinn und Zweck des Zustandspassivs anzetteln, sondern nur ein paar Fragen zum Verständnis stellen:

1. Vermutung: Der Zustandspassiv ist aktueller Stand der Wissenschaft und wird in allen Lehrbüchern so behandelt. Die prädikative Interpretation eines Satzes im Zustandspassiv ist schlicht falsch. — Liege ich mir dieser Einschätzung richtig?
2. Kritik am Zustandspassiv ist zwar extrem selten, dann aber ausführlich begründet. Aber wo finde ich eine Begründung *für* die Einführung dieses Konstrukts?
3. Mein eigener Versuch einer Definition lautet so:

   > Die Konstruktion „*Subjekt* **ist** *Partizip-II*“ ist Zustandspassiv genau dann, wenn „*Subjekt* **ist** *Partizip-II* **worden**“ a) sinnvoll ist und b) dasselbe bedeutet.

   Wie genau trifft das den tatsächlichen Sachverhalt?

   Hier einige Beispiele, die hoffentlich möglichst viele Spezialfälle abdecken (Perfektbildung mit *sein*, intransitives oder reflexives Verb, andauernde Handlung):

   > - Der Zeiger ist gewandert + worden — (unsinnig)
   > - Ich bin gegangen + worden — (andere Bedeutung)
   > - Sie ist verliebt + worden — (unsinnig)
   > - Das Haus ist bewohnt + worden — (andere Bedeutung)
   > - Wir sind verloren + worden — (unsinnig)
   > - Der Krieg ist verloren + worden — Zustandspassiv
   > - Opa ist gestorben + worden — (unsinnig)
   > - Opa ist beerdigt + worden — Zustandspassiv
4. Eine analoge Definition ist auch für das Partizip I denkbar. Im Englischen mag das höchst nützlich sein, aber im Deutschen erscheint mir das völlig schwachsinnig (was manche Gelehrten offenbar nicht abschreckt). Habe ich hier etwas verpasst? Eine Recherche zu „Zustandsaktiv“ ergab zwar praktisch keine Treffer, aber vielleicht nennt man das ja anders. Hier einige Beispiele für „*Subjekt* **ist** *Partizip-I*“:

   > - Der Film ist spannend / spannt — (andere Bedeutung)
   > - Er ist wohlhabend / hat wohl — (unsinnig)
   > - Das Argument ist überzeugend / überzeugt — „Zustandsaktiv“?

   Oder darf ich all diese Partizipien weiterhin als Prädikativ betrachten?

Comment: Ich bin bei dir mit diesem Satz: *Intuitiv lese ich den zweiten Satz einfach als Kopula mit Prädikativ (syntaktisch äquivalent zu „Die Tür ist offen“). Damit habe ich mich neulich leider etwas blamiert.* - Aber es ist mir vollkommen egal, wenn ich mich blamiere..... Das "Zustandspassiv" finde ich ein bißchen weit hergeholt.

Comment: [Verwandte Frage auf Linguistics.SE auf Englisch](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/14372/10467) Ja, ich habe zur Einordnung auch so meine Vorbehalte ;)

Answer (score 4):

Irgendwie bin ich bei Teilen der Frage etwas verwirrt. Du schreibst: "Ich erkenne keinen Bezug zur Syntax. Der Zustandspassiv wird rein semantisch definiert und eignet sich damit bestenfalls als Stilmittel."

Dabei hast du die Konstruktion als mit *sein* und Partizip Präteritum (Partizip II / Partizip Perfekt (Passiv)) gebildet durchaus erkannt und syntaktisch charakterisiert.

Erst einmal sollten wir uns ausschließlich auf transitive (und nicht reflexive) Verben beschränken, denn das Zustandspassiv erfordert (im Ggs. zum Vorgangspassiv, das Ausdrücke wie *hier wird gearbeitet* erlaubt) notwendigerweise ein Subjekt, und das Subjekt eines Passivsatzes entspricht dem direkten Objekt des Aktivsatzes, welches per Definition nur transitive Verben haben. Der Großteil deiner Beispiel unter 3. ergibt damit a priori aus ganz grundsätzlichen passivtechnischen Gründen kein Zustandspassiv. Darüber hinaus muss ein Zustandspassiv mit einem Verb konstruiert werden, dass tatsächlich einen Resultatszustand hinterlässt.

Darüber hinaus ist es natürlich möglich, dass Partizipien als vollwertige Adjektive lexikalisiert werden. Das gilt beispielsweise für die Adjektive *spannend*, *wohlhabend* und *überzeugend*, die aus Partizipien Präsens (Aktiv) lexikalisiert worden sind. Dass diese Adjektive synchron nicht mehr grundsätzlich als Partizipien angesehen werden sollten, merkst du ja zumindest bei *spannend* und *wohlhabend* selber aufgrund der Bedeutung. Grundsätzlich kann das Partizip Präsens (bei dem, weil es aktivisch ist, keine semantische Beschränkung auf irgendwelche semantisch definierte Verbklassen vorliegt/vorliegen sollte) nicht prädikativ verwendet werden. Sätze wie *ich bin nehmend*, *sie ist kaufend*, *sie sind laufend* sind ungrammatisch.

Ich halte auch *geschlossen* und *geöffnet* für zumindest teilweise lexikalisiert, aber dazu unten mehr.

Dein Versuch, eine "*sein* + Partizip Präteritum"-Konstruktion dann als Zustandspassiv zu definieren, wenn sie dasselbe bedeutet wie das Perfekt eines Vorgangspassiv, krankt daran, dass die beiden Konstruktionen nicht dasselbe bedeuten.

Nehmen wir das Beispiel *Ich bin geschlagen* vs. *Ich bin geschlagen worden.*. Ersteres hat nur die Lesart, dass ich in einer Sache, bspw. einem Kampf, einem Spiel o.ä. geschlagen bin, mit einem Resultat, nämlich, dass das Ereignis vorbei und der Verlierer bekannt ist.

Der zweite Satz hat zwei Lesarten, nämlich diejenige, dass jemand mich in einem Kampf, Spiel o.ä. geschlagen hat oder, dass jemand mich mit Hand oder Gegenstand geschlagen hat. In letzterem Fall gibt es keinen notwendigen Resultatszustand. Willst du einen Resultatszustand hinzufügen, z.B. *sie hat ihn totgeschlagen*, so wird mit einem Mal auch wieder das Zustandspassiv akzeptabel: *er ist/war totgeschlagen* (vgl. Vorgangspassiv *er wird/wurde totgeschlagen*, *er ist/war totgeschlagen worden*).

Da Partizipien auch adjektivische Bedeutungen haben und auch das Partizip Präteritum attributiv verwendet werden kann (*Der geschlagene Gegner*, *der nervige Gegner*), hat sicherlich die Konstruktion des Zustandspassivs gemeinsamen Ursprung mit der einfachen prädikativen Adjektivkonstruktion, die syntaktisch vergleichbar ist (*der Gegner ist geschlagen*, *der Gegner ist nervig*).

Es ist trotzdem notwendig zu charakterisieren, dass man derartiges mit dem Partizip Präteritum machen kann und unter welchen Umständen das möglich ist (bspw. haben wir gesehen, dass es mit dem Partizip Präsens in prädikativer Stellung nicht funktioniert). Es gibt jetzt zwei Arten und Weisen, das zu charakterisieren.

Entweder sagt man, dass das Partizip Präteritum diese Eigenschaften in den oben genannten Fällen für sich hat und dann als Adjektiv mit stativer/resultativer Bedeutung fungiert, oder man definiert die Konstruktion als solche als Zustandspassiv. Ich sehe allerdings keinen notwendigen Widerspruch. Ich persönlich würde sagen, dass das Zustandspassiv eine bestimmte Verwendung adjektivisch gebrauchter Partizipien Präteritum ist. Man muss nur der Tatsache gerecht werden, dass das Zustandspassiv produktiv ist, bspw. ist *der Bug ist endlich weggecodet* ein völlig akzeptabler Satz in meinem Idiolekt trotz der jungen Entlehnung von *coden* und meiner Spontanbildung mit dem resultativen *weg*.

Was nun *geöffnet* und *geschlossen* angeht und warum ich sie zumindest für teillexikalisiert erachte, so liegt das daran, dass man sie in Konstruktionen wie *Dieser Laden hat geöffnet/geschlossen* verwenden kann, was nur ganz bestimmten Adjektiven vorbehalten ist. Aber womöglich braucht man bei einer rein adjektivischen Analyse der Partizipien diesen Lexikalisierungsunterschied nicht zu machen.

Noch ein paar Sachen zur Terminologie. Ich würde hier nicht von einem dritten Genus Verbi sprechen. Zustandspassiv und Vorgangspassiv sind dann doch recht ähnliche Bildungen (beide verwenden das Partizip Präteritum, beide verwenden Hilfsverben, die auch aus anderen Konstruktionen bekannt sind, beide lassen das direkte Objekt eines transitiven Verbs zum Subjekt werden). Es sind zwei etwas unterschiedliche Bildungen ein- und desselben Genus Verbi.

Ein drittes Genus Verbi ließe sich eher im noch eher alltagssprachlichen (aber zunehmend auch in förmlichen Texten auftauchenden) Dativ-Passiv mit *kriegen*, *bekommen*, selten auch *erhalten* (*Hans bekam ein Fahrrad geschenkt*, *ich kriege das morgen mitgeteilt*) erkennen.

Darüber hinaus ist sowohl im Zustands- als auch im Vorgangspassiv das Partizip als prädikativ zu betrachten. Prädikativ ist dasjenige Satzglied, welches eine Aussage macht und die Argumente des Satzes bedingt/auswählt, meistens ein Verb, in einigen Fällen ein Adjektiv, eine Nominalphrase oder etwas anderes (dann im Deutschen typischerweise mit Hilfsverb *sein*/*werden* o.ä.).

Was übrigens den aktuellen Stand der Wissenschaft angeht, so würde ich nicht in Lehrbüchern suchen, sondern in linguistischen Artikeln. Die Definitionen und Beschreibungen in Lehrbüchern und Grammatiken für den Alltagsgebrauch sind oft um Jahrzehnte veraltet, und das oft auch aus gutem Grund. Bisweilen stellen sich linguistische Sachverhalte als sehr komplex heraus, sodass man sicherlich über das Thema des Zustandspassiv im Deutschen allein mehr als éine Dissertation verfassen kann und weswegen meine Beschreibung hier sicherlich nicht jedem einzelnen Detail, das du irgendwo zum Zustandspassiv findest, gerecht wird.

Comment: ich sehe erst einmal keinen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen prädikativer und attributiver Verwendung eines adjektivischen Partizips wie *geschlagen*, und deswegen muss ich mich schon wundern, warum hier plötzlich eine Passivform aufgemacht wird …

Answer (score 2):

Tatsächlich wurde das Zustandspassiv in der Wissenschaft schon diskutiert. Das Problem ist schlicht, dass es nicht grammatikalisiert genug ist. Vergleichen wir, indem wir zunächst verschiedene Vorgangspassivkonstruktionen auflösen:

> Der Hund wird gestreichelt.
> Der Hund wird ein gestreichelter Hund.

Hier kann das Vorgangspassiv stark auf die lexikalische Bedeutung zurückführen - die aber ein Sprecher so nicht mehr wahrnimmt. Er hört nicht "The dog *becomes* petted". Dies kann an einem weiteren Beispiel demonstriert werden:

> Das Vorgangspassiv wird üblicherweise früh gelehrt.
> ?Das Vorgangspassiv wird üblicherweise ein früh gelehrtes.

Hier sind Vorgangspassiv und lexikalische Ebene sehr weit voneinander getrennt, was typisch ist für eine grammatikalisierte Form.

Beim Zustandspassiv wird das schwieriger:

> Der Hund ist gestreichelt.
> Der Hund ist ein gestreichelter Hund.
>
> ?Das Zustandspassiv ist früh gelehrt.
> ?Das Zustandspassiv ist ein früh gelehrtes.

Es fällt auf, dass das zweite Beispiel nicht richtig funktioniert. Generell kann ich kein Beispiel konstruieren, in dem das Zustandspassiv von der Bedeutung her über lexikalisch Kopula + Attribut hinausgeht.

Dementsprechend halte ich das Zustandspassiv tatsächlich nicht für grammatikalisiert, es ist jedoch für die Sprachlehre relativ sinnvoll, das so darzustellen.

Zu Deinen Beispielen noch etwas: es gibt auch werden + Attribut, das kein Passiv ist:

> Ich werde betrunken.

Das ist reine Kopula.

Hinsichtlich Partizip Präsens waren werden/sein + Partizip Präsens in der Vergangenheit (Mittelhochdeutsch, Althochdeutsch) in Verwendung:

> Die Musikanten werden spielend(e) -> Inchoativ
> Die Musikanten sind spielend -> Verlaufsform.

Der Inchoativ wurde häufig verwendet, um das lateinische Futur zu übertragen und wurde schließlich zum heutigen Futur, weil das -d(e) wegfiel.
Mit sein + Infinitiv gibt es noch den heutigen Absentiv, aber der ist meines Wissens nach eine "Neubildung" und keine Verschleifung des -d. Die es zwischendurch wohl auch gab, aber die bis zum 17. Jahrhundert zusehends unterging (ich suche den Beleg raus, wenn jemand möchte, ich habe einen).